# Datatables re-render on Mobile or Tablet when not in view

Tags: mobile, datatables, tablet

We have a strange issue, that can only be reproduced on a mobile or tablet device (it does not happen on a laptop/computer).
The datatable we are using is an inline editing datatable that is like excel (so all fields and all rows are always available for edit).

On a tablet or mobile device if I scroll so that the datatable is not fully in view (so part of the datatable is not showing), then when I go back to use the datatable (so click in a cell to select a drop down or type some text) the datatable re-renders.
The same happens if I scroll up to the top of the page, so the databtable is fully out of view and scroll around a bit it will also suddenly re-render the datatable as well.

Like I have said this never happens on a laptop/computer so I am not sure what the issue is.
On the mobile and tablet I have tested chrome for android and firefox.
Any ideas, would be very much appreciated!

Here is an example of one of the data tables and a screen shot

```
self.table = $(self.parentContainerSelector + ' table').DataTable({
scrollY: 300,
"scrollX": true,
paging: false,
order: [[$(self.parentContainerSelector + ' th.posno-column').index(), 'asc']],
data: self.DataForInitTable,
createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
self.checkRowForAnotherRules(row, data);
},
columnDefs: [
{
```

[Screenshot of datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnbMr.png)

Comment: The datatable also re-renders when editing a cell that is text (because the keypad comes up when using a tablet or phone).

Comment: We have also worked out that it calls the render for each column for each row, but never actually calls the draw for the table. So it is just an issue that render is called when not needed.